# CAs in different child domains

Tags: ssl, certificate

I am trying to achieve the following;

Environment is a Single Forest with a Root Domain and x2 child domains as follows;

root.net
child1.root.net
child2.root.net

There will be no logical or physical access between child1 and child2 as one will be a Production Domain and the other a Development Domain.

Both Domains require completely separate Certificate Services Authorities to distribute and manage internal certificates within their own domain only.  Both Domains will have their own separate Offline Root CA's.

Are there any gotchas with this setup (Any AD registration issues, etc) or is there a better way to deploy this, bearing in mind the AD setup cannot change? (Must retain Single Forest and x2 Child Domain model).

Comment: `Must retain Single Forest and x2 Child Domain model` That's rarely recommended anymore, and what you're describing just screams "different forests."  Other than that, I'm not sure what you're asking - are you asking if you can deploy different root CAs into child domains of the same forest?

Comment: Hi HopelessN00b, thanks for the reply.

No, the Root CA's for each Child Domain will be x2 separate Offline CA's.  Each Child Domain will have a Subordinate CA, each corresponding to the x2 Offline CA's (Offline CA's will be non-Domain connected).

In essence, I am trying to deploy separate CA hierarchies for each of the Child Domains.

Thanks.

Comment: While this would be possible in theory in practice no browser or other application will respect the restrictions for the CA, which in effect makes the restrictions moot.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for that.  Would you be able to elaborate on that?  Alternatively, what would you recommend?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to understand: ADCS is forest-wide service. That is, once Enterprise CA is installed, it is registered in Active Direcotry, configuration naming context. As you may know (at least, should know) that configuration naming context is replicated between **all** domain controllers in the forest.

Recently we had a similar discussion on TechNet forums, where I and Mark B. Cooper explained all diffculties with this scenario: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0594d63c-bfc3-4868-b173-1163cc0e997a/ca-query?forum=winserversecurity

in short, it is doable, however it will require additional management overhead and do not provide true isolation. In this case it is reasonable to split domains to separate forests (not easy task as well).

Answer (score 1):

So there will be two offline roots, one dedicated to each child domain?

Given the access restrictions you want, it seems like it'd make more sense to have the offline roots be in the child domains - since they're offline anyway, it's not like you're losing any security from it.

Presumably with an offline root, they'll be standalone and not enterprise, so you'll be manually deploying trust of those certs into each child domain?  Having them in the root domain just adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Hi Shane,

Yes, exactly that!

My concern was around the fact that CAs normally have Forest Wide scope (CN partition replication) & wanted to know if doing it this way would cause me any issue down the line or stop any functionality from working.

Also, as the certificate templates are Forest Wide, I'd want to only allow Domain1 certificates to deploy to Domain1, and Domain2 to deploy to Domain2.

Would the CAs in each domain be completely isolated in this scenario?  Even though they can't physically access each other, I can't have Event Log errors in the background because they are trying.

Comment: @Martin The bottom line is, if you require complete isolation, you need to split your AD into two forests.  That's what the forest boundary is there for.  Child domains have an implicit trust relationship with their root domain, and by extension, are never completely isolated from other child domains.

Comment: Thanks guys - appreciate the help and validation.  You've all been very helpful.

Comment: In the end I decided to take the advice here and on Technet (Thanks  CryptoGuy) and we're splitting things into separate AD Forests.

Appreciate everyone's input.